# Getting compile time error in onClick-cannot resolve "context"

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make my phone mute when I press the button "Mute" but keep getting the same error.
Here is the Code so far:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
}
```

`context` in `context.getSystem.<blah>` is red and cannot resolve. Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your method is in an `Activity`, you can just get rid of `context` and call `getSystemService()` directly

```
public void onClick(View v){
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
}
```